# Concatenate in C, like lists in Haskell

Tags: c, haskell

I've sort of ended up writing a translator from Haskell to C, a hobby thing..

Haskell's `(:)`-function, with type `a -> [a] -> [a]` is what I want to do in C.

`1 : [2,3]` is in fact `1 : (2 : (3 : []))` if I'm not mistaken.

Say I want to create an infinite list with increasing numbers in it:

```
lst i = i : lst (i + 1)
```

How do I do this in C? I imagine the final product looking something along the lines of:

```
int* lst(int i) {
    return cons(i, lst(i + 1));
}
```

My thought so far:

- C has arrays.
- Arrays need to be of a defined length, this clashes with recursive reasoning.
- C has pointers.

  - Arrays decay to pointers when passed as arguments anyway so, might as well use pure pointers.
  - `array[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + i)`, I'm thinking I can use this to get around the problem of having to define things you cannot know (final length of the list etc).

I'm unsure of the implementation of cons though.. My best guess is:

```
int* cons(int head, int *tail) {
    int *ptr;
    *(ptr + 1) = *tail;
    *ptr = head;
    return ptr;
}
```

Pointers are hard for me, dereferencing etc etc, I don't know C very well and my brain hurts. I just want to make a pointer which contains both the head and the tail. Order is not important for the moment.

It compiles, but that's as far as it goes. Help would be appreciated, I'm open to suggestions, I'm not even sure I'm on the right track or if it's even possible.

Comment: Okay, C doesn't have lazy evaluation, but I'm not trying to do this with infinite lists, it was just a simple example. I just want the basic functionality :)

Comment: Haskell can have infinite lists, because it has lazy semantics. That is, if you write something like `list = 1:list`, the cdr on the right-hand side is a "thunk", only evaluated, when needed. So your cdr must be a funtion pointer.

Comment: Well but lazy semantics is at the very core of Haskell.

Comment: Linked lists are closer to what you want.

Comment: Well he is building a linked lists .. with links on the stack, so everything will be smashed ...

Comment: C is a low-level language. It's used to push bits around in memory directly. You have to do memory management yourself. Doing high-level abstract things like you mention would require you to do your own garbage collection, your own tail-call optimization, and many other things that the high-level languages do for you. C isn't meant for such things.

Comment: A translator from Haskell to C is called a compiler. You probably don't want to write one. You especially probably don't want to write one from Haskell to C. It's possible to build GHC specially to make it one (generally crippling other features), but this is only useful for special purposes.

Comment: O, I missed something, the links are not even on the stack, the pointer is unitialized, thus pointing somewhere possibly even more sinister!

Comment: [there's no royal road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Road#A_metaphorical_.E2.80.9CRoyal_Road.E2.80.9D_in_famous_quotations) to writing Haskell-to-C translators. You need to really *really* know C very *very* well for that. It also requires being extremely comfortable with pointers, coincidentally.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish, anyway? Translating ideas from a high-level research language that's recently become somewhat practical to a decades-old lowish-level language slowly approaching obsolescence seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is what your function is doing:

```
int* cons(int head, int *tail) {
    int *ptr; // Declare a pointer on the stack
    *(ptr + 1) = *tail; // Set the int located after the one pointed by the (uninitialised) pointer ptr to the value pointed to by tail
    *ptr = head; // Set the value that the (still unitiliased) points to to head
    return ptr; // Return an uninitialised value
}
```

Second, what you want is a linked list. You can create a structure just like `data List a = [] | (:) a (List a)` in C. For example,

```
typedef struct list {
  void *element;
  struct list *next;
} list_t;
```

Now `cons` would look like this:

```
list_t *harp_cons(void *element, list_t *rest) {
  list_t *list  = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_t));
  list->element = element;
  list->next    = rest;
  return list;
}
```

This is allocating data on the heap, so you need to free it afterwards. You can provide a function `free_list` which would look like the following. (Assuming the elements can simply be freed with `free()` for the sake of simplicity.)

```
void free_list(list_t *list) {
  if(list != NULL) {
    if(list->next != NULL) {
      free_list(list->next);
    }
    free(list->element);
    free(list);
  }
}
```

I just took that code from some of my open source code.

If you want to look at a full implementation of (sort of) a list API: https://github.com/thoferon/harp/blob/master/libharp/list.c.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, it's quite a lot at once so forgive me if I don't yet realize you've solved my problem.
I have a question, I don't wanna sound stupid but, why is my pointer uninitialized..? And why does it matter, I thought I assigned it to something eventually...

Comment: How is it not uninitialized, @AndersE.Adrielsson? You never initialize it, but you use it on the lhs of an assignment. Please tell us where that pointer `ptr` is pointing to?

Comment: @Ingo is right, you never actually assign any value in this variable. `*ptr = ...` is not initialising, it assigns a value to the location pointed to by the pointer but it doesn't actually touch the pointer itself.

Comment: Alright, I follow you.. So what would make sense I initialize it to, in this context..?
ptr = tail; ? (or = &something I guess). Pointers are confusing

Comment: @AndersE.Adrielsson obviously, ptr must point to new memory (i.e., you are creating a new list node with (:))

Comment: Pointers contain a memory address. Even if some list was located at the address pointed to by tail, you would write to the memory before, thus corrupting the memory by overwriting other stuff and eventually try to modify an unreachable address and your program would crash.